# Ajustar la tabla a la ventana en python y con PySimpleGUI

Tags: python, pysimplegui

Me gustaria solicitar ayuda en como puedo ajustar esta tabla para que me abarque el campo del input y del boton, y al solicitar la busqueda se ajuste el contenido en las columnas,

les dejo la imagen y el codigo :

```
import PySimpleGUI as sg
import pandas as pd

archivo_df = pd.read_excel("C:\\Users\\Arturo Del Angel\\Downloads\\Laminas.xlsx", sheet_name='Base de datos')

column_widths = [5, 20, 20]

layout = [
    [sg.Text('Ingrese la busqueda')],
    [sg.Input(key='input_buscar'), sg.Button('Buscar')],
    [sg.Table(values=[], headings=archivo_df.columns.tolist(), key = '-TABLA-', num_rows = 10, col_widths=column_widths)]

    ]

window = sg.Window('Laminas', layout)

while True:
    event, values = window.read()
    if event == sg.WINDOW_CLOSED:
        break
    
    if event == 'Buscar':
        busqueda = values['input_buscar']
        resultados = archivo_df[archivo_df['Nombre'].str.contains(busqueda, case = False)]

        window['-TABLA-'].update(values=resultados.values.tolist())

window.close()
```

Comment: Por favor, agrega un imagen con el resultado que ahora obtienes y otra con el resultado deseado. Así se entenderá mejor.

Comment: Muchas Gracias, pero ya quedo,era la opcion expand . . .

Comment: Por cierto intente mandar una imagen y no me dejaron subirla ,

Comment: Estupendo. Ahora mejor elimina la pregunta pues es un caso tan particular.